# Thycotic Plugin for Rundeck Base Configuration Not Working

Tags: rundeck

I am trying to configure the Thycotic Plugin for Rundeck

I am following the documentation here but the service won't restart successfully after adding the suggested configuration:

https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/key-storage/storage-plugins/thycotic-storage.html

We are using Rundeck community version

APIVERSION : 41

BASE : C:\rundeck

BUILD : 4.5.0-20220811

BUILDGIT : v4.5.0-0-g5b820d3

NODE : redacted

SERVERUUID : redacted

VERSION : 4.5.0-20220811

This is the error from C:\rundeck\server\logs

nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Storage Plugin named "thycotic-storage" could not be loaded

Does anyone know if this Thycotic plugin has bugs in the default configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that this plugin is for enterprise only